# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in swift while calling function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I know there are many answers about this error but I cannot seem to figure it out. I am receiving the error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=257, address=0x200000003) on the line where the function is called. My table cell view controller is as follows.

```
import UIKit

class NewsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var postImageView: CustomImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var postTitleLabel:UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var authorLabel:UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

var article: Article? {
        didSet {
            postTitleLabel.text = article?.title
            authorLabel.text = article?.author
            dateLabel.text = article?.date

            setupArticleImage()
        }
}
func setupArticleImage() {
         postImageView.loadImageUsingUrlString("http://theblakebeat.com/uploads/873463.jpg")
}
```

This code calls the function loadImageUsingUrlString, which is located in my extensions.swift file. It is called for each table view cell that is loaded in order to load its image. The code for extensions.swift is as follows.

```
import UIKit

let imageCache = NSCache()

class CustomImageView: UIImageView {

    var imageUrlString: String?

    func loadImageUsingUrlString(urlString: String) {
        imageUrlString = urlString

        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

        image = nil

        if let imageFromCache = imageCache.objectForKey(urlString) as? UIImage {
        self.image = imageFromCache
        return
    }

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, respones, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data!)

            if self.imageUrlString == urlString {
                self.image = imageToCache
            }

            imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: urlString)
        })

    }).resume()
}

}
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you post the full error log?

Comment: Yes, could you give me info on how to do that? Im unsure of where to access the full error log. Thanks!

Comment: From the debugger itself. or you are getting `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=257, address=0x200000003)` only this content?

Comment: If I click through the various parts of the thread, I can also see

Comment: error: memory read failed for 0x200000000

Comment: what happen if you comment this line? `setupArticleImage()`

Comment: The error does not appear as that function is not called.

Comment: Which line exactly causes the error, since you mentioned that `setupArticleImage()` call causes error? Does error occurs inside `loadImageUsingUrlString` method?

Comment: postImageView.loadImageUsingUrlString("http://drippin.us/uploads/873463.jpg") is the line that shows up as red.

Comment: call `postImageView.loadImageUsingUrlString("http://drippin.us/uploads/873463.jpg")` directly instead of calling `setupArticleImage()`. see what happens.

Comment: Okay, I will have to wait until I am home later but will get back to you. Thank you so much! I am very stuck here.

Comment: I still received the same error when calling the function directly. Is there anything else I could try? Could I share my project file with you? Thank you so much.

Comment: Sure, you can share the project.

Comment: Thanks! I uploaded it to [link](https://github.com/neiljohn23/app3.git)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You did not set the class `CustomImageView` to the `postImageView` in the IBInspector:

[image: description]

Comment: Just minor things to remember :)

Comment: Also double check if the "Module" is correct. An easy way to do it is typing again the class name and hit Enter - the module will be automatically filled if the class exists anywhere in your project

Answer (score 0):

Your `extensions.swift` is in the right Target?

In XCode select the file in Project Navigator and check in File Inspector the section `Target Membership`

Comment: Yes, they all have the same 'membership' box checked. Is there anything else I can try?